# Why this oops concept code is not working?

Tags: oop, dart

I am new in Dart. I am surprised why this OOPs not working!

```
class MicroPhone {


 String name;
  String color;
  int model;
}

main() {
  var mic = new MicroPhone();
  mic.name = " Blue Yeti";
  mic.color = "Silver";
  mic.model = 1234;
  print(mic);
}
```

in output said :

```
test.dart:3:10: Error: Field 'name' should be initialized because its type 'String' doesn't allow null.
  String name;
         ^^^^
test.dart:4:10: Error: Field 'color' should be initialized because its type 'String' doesn't allow null.
  String color;
         ^^^^^

test.dart:5:7: Error: Field 'model' should be initialized because its type 'int' doesn't allow null.
  int model;
      ^^^^^
```

Can you explain that why?

Comment: copying your code to https://dartpad.dev/? it works just fine. where are you trying to run it?

Comment: It won't work on dartpad if you flip the NNBD switch at the bottom!

Comment: @BenediktJSchlegel Thanks Its working on dartpad.dev. ! I am using Vs code. Thats for why I hate vscode sometimes.

Comment: The problem was not VSC.  You were just using the latest Dart. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're apparently using the Non-Null By Default (NNBD) version of Dart.  The three member variables need to be initialized to something that is not null (via a constructor which you don't have), *or* you have to tell Dart that it's ok for them to be null by following the types with question mark.

There is documentation on how to live in a pre-NNBD world at dart.dev, but it'd be better if you just get used to it this way for the future.  See https://dart.dev/null-safety for details.

Comment: I am using Vscode. It is not working on VsCode. But It is working on dartpad.dev . Thanks.

Comment: And the problem is not vscode vs dartpad, it is pre-NNBD dart vs post-NNBD dart.